# Using multiprocessing Lock() to prevent corrupt plots from being generated

Tags: python-2.7, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, ubuntu-18.04, multicore

With matplotlib backend set to 'PDF', I have incorporated plotting into a function. The central theme of the function is to produce plots, like so:

```
def func(arg1,arg2,arg3,num):
    try:
        fig = pdf.savefig(num+arg1+arg2,bbox_inches = "tight")
        return fig
    except:
        return None
```

I have been able to successfully obtain desired `results` (plots) in a serial manner with the following implementation:

```
data = list(range(100))
results=[func(arg1,arg2,arg3,num) for num in data]
```

I have attempted to implement this in a parallelized way using both pool.map() and pool.apply_async() methods as follows:

The pool.map() implementation:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        pool = Pool()    
        data = list(range(50))
        funct = partial(func,arg1,arg2,arg3)
        results = pool.map(funct, data)
    finally:
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

The pool.async() implementation:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        pool = Pool()    
        results = []
        data = list(range(50))
        result_objects = [pool.apply_async(func, args=(arg1,arg2,arg3,num)) for num in data]
        results = [r.get() for r in result_objects]
    finally:
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

With both the parallel implementations, I have noticed that out of the 50 simulations, only six results in a readable pdf file while others are corrupt. When I change the number of simulations to say ten, only three result in a readable pdf file while others are corrupt.

I don't seem to understand why only a few plots are appropriately produced while others are corrupted.

I am carrying out the multiprocessing using a 4 core Linux Ubuntu 18.04 machine.

I have come across the multiprocessing `queue()` module which seems to take care of communication between master and child processes. I guess that there is some fault in how the communication is happening currently, and thus resulting in corrupt images for most of the iterations.

Would like help in incorporating multiprocessing `queue()` into the code to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was under the presumption that Queue() might have some magical abilities to iron out the wrinkles in the code.

Going through several [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20742637/understanding-multiprocessing-shared-memory-management-locks-and-queues-in-pyt?rq=1), I realized that Lock() had the potential to unlock my misery.

The following modified code works fine:

The pool.map() implementation:

```
def func(arg1,arg2,arg3,lock,num):
    with lock:
        #your code#

from multiprocessing import Pool, Lock, Manager
from functools import partial
import time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try: 
        pool = Pool()
        m = Manager()
        lock = m.Lock()
        data = list(range(1000))
        funct = partial(func,arg1,arg2,arg3,lock)
        results = pool.map(funct, data)
    except:
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

The pool.async() implementation:

```
def func(num,arg1,arg2,arg3,lock):
    with lock:
        # your code #

from multiprocessing import Pool, Lock, Manager
from functools import partial
import time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        pool = Pool()
        m = Manager()
        lock = m.Lock()
        results = []
        data = list(range(1000))
        result_objects = [pool.apply_async(func, args=(num,arg1,arg2,arg3,lock)) for num in data]
        results = [r.get() for r in result_objects]
    finally:
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```